# Merge arrays from multi arrays

Tags: javascript

I have arrays:

> - Array 1: **["L", "S"]**
> - Array 2: **["Red", "Blue"]**

how to merge them =
**["L", "Red"], ["L", "Blue"], ["S", "Red"], ["S", "Blue"]**
 ?
Please help me, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? *(hint: **nested loop**)*. And this isn't called "merging", try to read about [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Answer (score -1):

For every element in your first array, you're going to want to add arrays for every element in your second array - nested for (forEach) loops do the job like this:

```js
let arr1 = ["L", "S"];
let arr2 = ["Red", "Blue"];
let output = [];

arr1.forEach(el => {
  arr2.forEach(el1 => {
    output.push([el, el1]);
  });
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of **nested loops**, but in case you want something shorter:

```
var arr1 = ['L', 'S'];
var arr2 = ['Red', 'Blue'];

let output = arr1.reduce((acc, e1) => acc.concat(arr2.map(e2 => [e1, e2])), [])
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired output. It just produces `["L", "Red"], ["S", "Blue"]`

Comment: Wasn't me, if that's who you're asking